# one database with different options tables for 2 wordpress sites

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have 2 WordPress websites (or, actually one server with 2 domains) `first.com` and `second.com`, and I want them to share the same database, except some tables that I want to be different for each site.

Let's say I want the "options" table, to be different for `first.com`.

I tried to edit in `wp-includes/wp-db.php:270` and renamed the table accordingly, but I got an error. So,  I guess this is not the right solution.

Could anybody please try to help me with this.

Thanks in advance

Edit 1:

I don't want them to share the same files, I only want them to share most of the tables in the database (but not all of them). is it possible?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this specific feature? If yes feel free to answer your own question :)

Answer (score 0):

Is it the same site but with a two different domain? You might want to use multiple domain point to a single host and use a multiple domain plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/multiple-domain/.

Comment: As far as I understand, this is not a solution, since I want some tables in the DATABASE to be different for each site.

Comment: I guess you may want to build multisite wordpress network. https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network

Comment: No, I need them to have separate files, I just want them to share some tables in the DataBase